# Why addSubview: with autolayout adds a subview with bad size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, addsubview

I have an UIView in a UIViewController. I'm using Objective-c and autolayout storyboards. This is an easy step: add a UIView programmatically into my storyboard's UIView.

I'm using this code:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:myStoryboardView.frame];
[newView setNeedsLayout];
[myStoryboardView addSubview:newView];
```

I also tried using the bounds instead of the frame:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:myStoryboardView.bounds];
[newView setNeedsLayout];
[myStoryboardView addSubview:newView];
```

But when I run this, the width is wrong, isn't like the width of my first UIView. However, if I change the storyboard to the same storyboard that the simulator that I'm using to run the application, the width is same in both UIViews...

How can I do it to set a width automatically same that my firts view into the storyboard.

Comment: try setting `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on your `newView` and `clipsToBounds` to `true`

Comment: I'm adding this code after and before add my newView to the view in storyboard and it isn't working [newView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    newView.clipsToBounds = YES;   How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If he disables autosizing mask translation he will need to setup top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints on his view. This is still preferred over relying on autosizing but I digress... Anyhow if parent view frame is non-zero it should work without tinkering with those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure that the myStoryboardView.frame is correct at that point? Where are you executing this code? It could be that at this point the storyboard view is just initialized from the storyboard file(where it has the frame you set in IB) and not yet adjusted to the screen size, which happens later. Try putting this code in the viewWillApper method if you're using a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

try to allocate this new subview somewhere in viewDidLoad. then in viewDidAppear set its frame to superview bouds:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  UIView *view = UIView.new;
  view.tag = 100; // or store it as a property
  [storyboardView addSubview:view];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [[storyboardView viewWithTag:100] setFrame:storyboardView.bounds];
}
```